# Adding Vouchers to Customers Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where we need to add distinct 3000 vouchers for customers on first come first serve basis (Customer is eligible Only once) for who have completed the recharger of $10 or More.

1. The table **customer** Consists Phone Number but doesn't have vouchers column.
2. **Vouchers** table doesn't have vouchers Column but dosn't have Phone Numbers.

Need to create new table for assigning distinct vouchers to phone numbers when the customer completes a recharge.

Thanks in Advance.

We created a table for customer who have completed a recharge but unable to assign Unique vouches as there is no primary (or any key ) in the Vouchers table. Also we tried with the help of Row ID but the Transactions Table gets truncated as it has to run for every 5 Minutes.(before truncating we are adding the customers to a back up table to exclude as there is no duplicates.)

Comment: may I ask why you don't just add some primary keys to your tables?

Comment: Yes, Have added Phone Number as primary key for Customer and Voucher_Code is Primary for Voucher. Also tried Row_Number its all good on First run but from run 2 its not matching.

Comment: okay but then just make a table like customervouchlink and link a vouch to a customer?

Comment: Hi, but have no idea on how to link the voucher post creating the table customervouchlink.

Comment: You insert a record into the  customervouchlink (which has columns for phone number and voucher code) which has the voucher code value and the phone number you want to link it to